# Profiling shows a leak in every iteration of a loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, memory-leaks

Profiling tells that there is an `MSVenue` object leak in each iteration, and an array object leak.

[image]

`fetchedRecords` is an array returned from the `executeFetchRequest:` method, that I'm sure returns an autoreleased array.

```
-(NSArray *)getSavedVenues
{
    NSMutableArray *venues = [[@[] mutableCopy] autorelease];
        for (Venues *venueManagedObject in fetchedRecords)
        {
            MSVenue *tmp = [[MSVenue alloc] init];
            [tmp setID:venueManagedObject.venueID];
            [tmp setName:venueManagedObject.venueName];

            [venues addObject:tmp];
            [tmp release];
            tmp = nil;
        }

        return [NSArray arrayWithArray:venues];
}
```

Comment: This one looks strange:
`NSMutableArray *venues = [[@[] mutableCopy] autorelease];`, why don't you just create instance of NSMutable array instead of creating mutable copy of NSArray?

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk - Yeah, I doubt that it's the problem, but it's kinda dumb.  `[NSMutableArray array]` accomplishes the same thing more clearly and efficiently.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are we seeing iterations of the above `for` loop, or iterations of some loop outside this method?  The above code will "accumulate" an MSVenue object with each iteration, since that's what you're placing in the array.  This is perfectly normal.

Comment: @HotLicks as `@[]` is equal to `[NSArray new]`, there will be allocated NSArray, with no references to it, no?

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using ARC? (Hint: enable ARC)

Comment: @Fogmeister it's may be old project

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk that's fine if it is but there's no harm in asking. Or indeed in enabling it in an old project if that is the case.

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk - I was agreeing with you.  Silly to create a immutable (and empty) array and then copy it to create a mutable array.

Comment: @Fogmeister : Yes I have to work on this project without ARC.

Comment: @MykolaDenysyuk : Yes the [@[] mutableCopy] was the reason. thank you. Actually I used to write it this way in ARC. But It is really dumb I'll stop creating mutable arrays this way.

Comment: But I still have the MSVenue leaks. but now it is not leaking from "getSavedVenues" method it is from

[RKObjectMappingOperationDataSource mappingOperation:targetObjectForRepresentation:withMapping:inRelationship:]
So I think now my method is clean.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing:

`[tmp setName:venueManagedObject.venueName];`

to

`[tmp setName:[NSString stringWithString:venueManagedObject.venueName]];`

Depending on how you've declared the Name property in MSVenue, you may be creating a strong reference to the other object's `venueName`, preventing that object from being released.  This is a circular reference - `fetchedRecords` won't be autoreleased until all the objects that reference it are released, and they won't be released until `fetchedRecords` is released.

Same with venueId, unless it's a scalar type (e.g. NSInteger).

Comment: There's never really a reason to use stringWithString, unless the parm is a mutable string.

Comment: You have a misconception about "belongs to another object".